# Generic GDI+ error when saving an image?

Tags: c#, exception, installshield

I want to save in image to other folder but it throw this Exception `system.runtime.interopservices.externalexception (0x80040005)`
this is my code :

```
pictureBox1.Image.Save(@"" + Application.StartupPath + "\\Image" + "".ToString() + @"\" + @"personeli_" + textBox4.Text + ".jpg");
```

This program works when I run it in visual studio but when I create setup file with InstallShield it throw an Exception .

Comment: I suspect the file is still open by some other part of your program, so you can't write to it. Do you use `Image.FromFile` on this file?

Comment: no , I don't use it .

Comment: Ah, the lovely _Generic GDI+ error_. Try `new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image).Save( /* your params here */ );`

Comment: @cubrr I try this but it doesn't word .

Comment: Does it work if you save to a different file?

Comment: yes , now I try it and save in other drive and works  .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a same problem and after a long search, I change the folder and my program works .I think if you use this code , your program run .
first I create a directory in `C`drive

```
if (!Directory.Exists((@"C:\Image")))
     Directory.CreateDirectory((@"C:\Image"));
```

and after that I save picture into it .

```
 new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image).Save(@"C:\Image" + @"\" +/* your file name */+ ".jpg");
```

I hope it works for you ;)